# VirtualBox : Access localhost:8080 in host browser

Tags: php, ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

I have this PHP application where I have to open it from Ubuntu because it uses an extension. In the application folder there is application guide file which contains this instructions:

1. Install VirtualBox
2. Open VirtualBox and click file->import appliance->Browse directory file 208.ova->import
3. start Ubuntu server
4. Login Ubuntu using given username and password
5. open XAMPP and paste this URL into the browser
   `localhost:8080`

I have successfully done 1-4. But when I try to access `localhost:8080` it won't open. I have searched on google and some solutions say i have to use host-only adapter or NAT, but it doesn't work. My friend tried it on his laptop and it works. My host is windows 10. Can someone help me?

I am really new to VirtualBox and Ubuntu, please explain clearly on a newbie level :)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you running the browser on the host or in the guest (inside the VM)?

Comment: i run it in host browser

Comment: Then you should not be using localhost (which connects to the host machine) but the IP-address of the virtual machine. Treat it like it's any other machine in your network and set up networking in VirtualBox (I'm sure there's tutorials for that).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you did the following after starting the XAMPP software: Press on ‘Start’ in the ‘Actions’ for Apache.

If you did this and it still doesn't work, can you show us the last entries in your Apache log file?